# vectorise nested iterations by using groupby methods

Tags: python, pandas, iteration, vectorization, euclidean-distance

I have written code to iterate through a dataset that has a demarcation column. This column consist of a value shared by all equally demarked rows.  The code iterate through each demarcated section with a nested loop to iterate through each line, finding the nearest neighbor for each row in its respective demarcated block

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

Create a df with XYZ and Section demark

```
p=5
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 3), columns=list('XYZ'))
df2 = df.sort('Z')
df2 = df2.reset_index(drop=True)
df2['Section_demark'] = (df2.index/p).astype('int')


df2.head(15)
      X         Y         Z            Section_demark
0    -1.125526 -0.249091 -2.505444     0 
1    0.710114   1.357477 -2.195904     0 
2   -0.580319  -0.997311 -2.031280     0 
3    1.311526  -0.268590 -1.741079     0 
4    0.481450   0.448904 -1.546278     0 
5   -1.820224  -0.846628 -1.392700     1 
6    0.528618   0.418862 -1.388170     1 
7    0.360560  -0.309429 -1.319548     1 
8   -0.369107  -1.290528 -1.233815     1 
9    0.139063   0.045076 -1.209820     1 
10   0.049387   1.087300 -1.188375     2 
11   0.678247  -1.191882 -1.172214     2 
12  -0.976294  -0.752081 -1.092286     2 
13   0.875952   0.319304 -1.079185     2 
14   0.469730  -0.329548 -1.044178     2
```

Function for euclidean distance

```
def eucl_d(item_id):
    a = df3.sub(df3.iloc[item_id], axis=1)
    b = np.sum( np.square(a), axis=1 )
    return b
```

Iterate through the section demarks, iterate through the lines in each Section_demark and find nearest neighbor,
Isolate the row nearest to top row and create a series, take the ix for that series and compile a list from it.
read the list back to df2, creating a new column with the Nearest neighbor index number as value

```
s=0
elements = []
while s<(len(df2)/p):
    df3 = df2[df2['Section_demark']==(s)]
    r=0
    while r<(p):   
        df4=df3.copy()
        df4['dist'] = eucl_d(r)
        df4 = df4.sort('dist')
        ser = df4.iloc[1]
        elements.append(ser.name)
        r=r+1
    s=s+1
df2["NNIX"] = elements

df2.head(10)

     X1       Y1        Z1        NNIX
0    0.002299 1.284195 -1.604009   1 
1   -0.444305 0.346856 -2.396538   0 
2   -0.490741 -1.416682 -1.423573  3 
3    0.203635 -0.676841 -1.596332  2 
4    0.002299 1.284195 -1.604009   1 
5   -0.314330 0.036554 -1.153127   6 
6   -0.387839 0.129000 -1.235331   5 
7   -0.314330 0.036554 -1.153127   6 
8   -0.059477 -0.205260 -1.136376  7 
9   0.717980 0.130665 -1.040372    8
```

I would like to exchange the last section of iteration with a groupby command and use aggregate or apply to run the eucl_d function, but it eludes me

I can get df2 grouped by running this:

```
grouped = df3.groupby('Section_demark')
```

Its the second step that is giving me trouble
I was thinking:

```
grouped.agg(eucl_d(item_id))
```

But I dont know how to specify the item_id for eucl_d(item_id)